# How do i remove a value in array ?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$abc = array( 1 ,2, 3, 4, 5  934, ......);
```

Now i want to remove particular value from the array without any loop since my array can contain n number of values.

```
Note : Value will not be repeated.
```

Comment: What is without loop? Or you will scan the array, or array_search

Comment: How would you decide which value to remove?

Comment: If you want often and quick remove items from array, make the flip one [1=>1, 2=>1, 3=>1...]. the opeeration `unset($abc[$key]);` does not scan array

Comment: That one is good solution @splash58

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
<?php
  $key = array_search(5, $abc);
  if($key!==false) unset($abc[$key]);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of `unset()` and `array_search()`

```
$search = 4;
unset($abc[array_search($search, $abc)]);
```